# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named (projectname.appname)

Tags: python, django

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Dhiraj(models.Model):
name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
email=models.EmailField(max_length=100)
password=models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import fields
from .models import Dhiraj
class StudentRegistation(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    models=Dhiraj
    fields=['name','email','password']
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Dhiraj

@admin.register(Dhiraj)
class DhirajAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display=('id','name','email','password')
```

views.py

```
from crudproject1.enroll.forms import StudentRegistation
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import StudentRegistation

def add_show(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    fm=StudentRegistation(request.post)
else:
    fm=StudentRegistation(request.post)
    context={
        'fm':fm
    }
return render(request,'enroll/addandshow.html')
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from enroll import views

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', views.add_show, name="addandshow")
]
```

error message

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
 -------
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\Desktop\dhiraj\crudproject1\crudproject1\urls.py", line 18, in <module>
  from enroll import views
  File "C:\Users\Dhiraj Subedi\Desktop\dhiraj\crudproject1\enroll\views.py", line 1, in <module>
  from crudproject1.enroll.forms import StudentRegistation
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'crudproject1.enroll'
```

I am creating a Django application and I am facing this issue can you please help

`

Comment: Please share the filetree.

Answer (score 0):

You can import your `StudentRegistation` (likely this should be renamed to `StudentRegistration`) from the `forms` module of the same app. You thus import this with:

```
from enroll.forms import StudentRegistation
```

or relative with:

```
from .forms import StudentRegistation
```

Comment: the file tree is upload.    please check

Comment: @Dhiraj: I don't see any edit with the filetree. This should show which files are in which directory.